# SQL Server 2008 throws "Declare table variable" errors

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

SQL Server 2008 throws errors when trying to write following query to create a stored procedure:

```
DECLARE @T table (TimeId uniqueIdentifier)     

INSERT INTO @T 
   SELECT DISTINCT ref1.value( './@v', 'uniqueIdentifier')  
   FROM @xmlTimeIds.nodes('/a/i') T(ref1) 

UPDATE TAB1  
SET TAB1.TMAT_INVOICED_HOURS = 0    
FROM dbo.TMAT_TimeRegisterAttribute AS TAB1   
INNER JOIN @T  on TAB1.TMAT_AT_GUID =  @T.TimeId    
WHERE TAB1.TMAT_TN_GUID = @guidTenantId
```

Comment: Are you going to show the errors?

Comment: the error, your stored procedure code might help

Comment: I'd assume, that the error message tells you, which variable was found undeclared. There are several... Just declare your variables with a fitting type and see what's happening.

Comment: @duffin,@abhishek .The procedure gives error message that @T variable is not declared

Comment: Please forgive me. I am very new to stackoverflow . So may be asking my question in little informal way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give @T an alias in the update sql.  The compiler regards @T as a variable rather than a table.

```
DECLARE @T table (TimeId uniqueIdentifier)     

INSERT INTO @T 
   SELECT DISTINCT ref1.value( './@v', 'uniqueIdentifier')  
   FROM @xmlTimeIds.nodes('/a/i') T(ref1) 

UPDATE TAB1  
SET TAB1.TMAT_INVOICED_HOURS = 0    
FROM dbo.TMAT_TimeRegisterAttribute AS TAB1   
INNER JOIN @T TempTable on TAB1.TMAT_AT_GUID =  TempTable.TimeId    
    WHERE TAB1.TMAT_TN_GUID = @guidTenantId
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `on` repeated twice: `INNER JOIN @T on on TAB1.TMAT_AT_GUID =  @T.TimeId`. Should be like this:

```
DECLARE @T table (TimeId uniqueIdentifier)     

INSERT INTO @T 
   SELECT DISTINCT ref1.value( './@v', 'uniqueIdentifier')  
   FROM @xmlTimeIds.nodes('/a/i') T(ref1) 

UPDATE TAB1  
SET TAB1.TMAT_INVOICED_HOURS = 0    
FROM dbo.TMAT_TimeRegisterAttribute AS TAB1   
INNER JOIN @T on TAB1.TMAT_AT_GUID =  @T.TimeId    
WHERE TAB1.TMAT_TN_GUID = @guidTenantId
```